Error: Could not find npm package 'expo-template-default@latest' when creating a new Expo app
I am trying to create a new Expo app using npx create-expo-app@latest on my Ubuntu system, but I keep encountering an error. Here are the steps I followed and the error message I received:

Ran the command:
npx create-expo-app@latest

Provided the name for my app:
✔ What is your app named? … app1

Encountered the following error:
✖ Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: Could not find npm package "expo-template-default@latest"
Error: Could not find npm package "expo-template-default@latest"


System Information

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Node.js Version: 20.13.1
npm Version: 10.8.0

I am looking for a solution to resolve the error with npx create-expo-app@latest as it is the preferred method for setting up new projects in my workflow. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've fixed this error by specifying the template URL from github
Run:
npx create-expo-app@latest app-name --template https://github.com/expo/expo-template-default


It works for me but creates a typescript default app. I want a blank project, any workaround?

Generally this error occurred in Ubuntu OS when you install nodejs from Snapstore or App Center.
You can solve this error by following these steps:

Uninstall Nodejs from snapstore.
Install nodejs from official website or using NVM.

